# MongoDB replica set configuration crashed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

**Overview**: I have a 3 member replica set configuration. 1 primary, 1 secondary and 1 arbiter. All 3 are running and are in perfect sync with each other.

**Problem**: All the instances were stopped for server maintenance. They were started in the following order:

1. Primary instance.
2. Secondary instance.
3. Arbiter instance.

After all the 3 instance services were started, the arbiter failed to start correctly in the replica set. Upon checking the logs, I found the following line being printed repeatedly

```
Thu Jul 12 18:32:20 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (yet)
Thu Jul 12 18:32:30 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (yet)
Thu Jul 12 18:32:40 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (yet)
Thu Jul 12 18:32:50 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (yet)
```

**Steps performed to resolve:**

1. Stopped the arbiter instance.
2. Deleted the local db files from arbiter's data folder.
3. Removed the instances from the replica set (including secondary).
4. Started the arbiter instance.
5. Added both the secondary and arbiter instance to the replica set

---

I am trying to figure out the following questions:

1. Why is the above log statement printed repeatedly?
2. What might be the cause of such an issue?

Comment: Did you check if the IP addresses are the same after the servers restarted?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Martin.
Yes, I did. The IP addresses as well as the port numbers are correct.